# Prove there is an integer larger than a given real number

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers

A homework problem guides me to prove that there is a rational number $\frac{m}{n}$ between every two real numbers $x$ and $y$. The first step requires me to prove that there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{y-x} < n$. That you can always find a natural number larger than any given real number seems trivial obvious to me, but I can't figure out how to prove it. I thought of trying to use the fact that there is no largest natural number, but that doesn't prove that there is always one larger than a given real number. The assignment says that I can use the fact that $\frac{1}{y-x}$ has a decimal expansion to prove this first step, but I don't see how that helps.

Can someone please help me figure out how to prove that there exists an integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{y-x} < n$ for all real $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Have you heard of the Archimedean Property?

Comment: When needing to prove some "trivial" result you need to have a clear picture of what axioms you are beginning with. Your question appears to be lacking any statement about that.

Comment: But between $\frac1{y-x}$ and $(\frac1{y-x})+1$ might be a logical place to look for such a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y-x>0$, by [Archimedean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) property, there exits $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n(y-x)>1$

[For, suppose it is false. Then we have $n \leq \frac{1}{y-x}, \forall n.$ which means $\frac{1}{y-x}$ is an upper bound for $\Bbb{N}$, a contradiction! ]

Question : Why we need that ?

> Answer:
>
> Assuming the existence of such an $\frac{m}{n}$ with $n > 0$. So, we have $x < \frac{m}{n}<y$.
> That is, $nx < m < ny$. Thus we are claiming that the interval
> $(nx, ny)$ contains an integer. It is geometrically obvious that a sufficient condition
> for an interval $J = (nx, ny)$ to have an integer in it is that its length $ny-nx$ is greater
> than $1$.That is , $n(y-x)>1$. Archimedean
> property assures of such $n$'s.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use decimal expansion?

Comment: Wow, I forgot to accept an answer. Sorry that took me so long.